# why ls reports a huge file and du does not?

Tags: ls, disk-usage

When I run `arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary add.elf add.bin` everything seems to be ok. But, later when I run `ls -lh add.bin add.elf` this is the output I received:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2,6G nov 23 22:49 add.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david 65K nov 23 22:40 add.elf
```

this is a huge file. But when I run `du -h add.bin` the output is:

```
8,0K    add.bin
```

What's happening here?

Edit:
Output of `arm-none-eabi -A -t -x add.bin`:

```
 Warning: could not locate 'add.bin'.  reason: Value too large for defined data type
```

Output of `arm-none-eabi -A -t -x add.elf`:

```
section           size         addr
.text             0x2c          0x0
.data              0xc   0xa0000000
.ARM.attributes   0x14          0x0
Total             0x4c
```

Output of `du -bh add.bin`:

```
2,6G    add.bin
```

This is how I fixed it:

Initially when I link the program with the command `arm-none-eabi-ld -Tld_script.lds -o add.elf add.o` the ld script file `ld_script.lds` contains this:

```
SECTIONS {
        . = 0x00000000;
        .text : { 
                * (.text); 
        }

        . = 0xA0000000;  /* RAM starting address */
        .data :{ 
                * (.data); 
        }
}
```

The above code fills from 0x00000000 to 0xA0000000 with 0s.
This error can be solved the following way:

```
SECTIONS {
        . = 0x00000000;
        .text : { 
                * (.text); 
        }
        flash_sdata = .; /* Start data in flash right after the text */

        . = 0xA0000000;  /* RAM starting address */
        ram_sdata = .;

        /* AT specifies the load addr. of .data section */
        .data : AT (flash_sdata) { 
                * (.data); 
        }
        ram_edata = .;   /* Address of end of data in RAM */
        data_size = ram_edata - ram_sdata;
}
```

And then in the source I added a piece to copy the data from Flash to RAM. Something like this:

```
        @ Copy data to RAM.
start:
        ldr   r0, =flash_sdata
        ldr   r1, =ram_sdata
        ldr   r2, =data_size

copy:
        ldrb  r4, [r0], #1
        strb  r4, [r1], #1
        subs  r2, r2, #1
        bne   copy
```

If my English is not too precise, this is the [link](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/data-in-ram.html) which helps me to fix the problem. (And a good site for learning ARM embedded programming).

Comment: This thread sounds like it's related to your Q: http://embdev.net/topic/150574

Comment: On the surface this looks like either the resulting .bin file isn't getting compressed *or* it's including memory (.data) sections in your .bin file that are causing it to be sized inappropriately too large.

Comment: What does this command report for the resulting files? `arm-none-eabi-size.exe -A -t -x <file>`.

Comment: What's the output of `du -bh add.bin`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that `add.bin` is a sparse file.

Most unix file systems support sparse files (of almost arbitrary sizes). Basically, you can seek to an arbitrary offset before starting to write, and the blocks you skip over will not actually be mapped to disk. If you try to read them, they'll be full of 0s. If you write to them, they'll magically spring into existence (but only the ones you write to).

Here's an example:

```
$ dd of=sparse obs=1K seek=1M if=<(echo foo)
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
4 bytes (4 B) copied, 0.000411909 s, 9.7 kB/s
$ ls -lh sparse
-rw-r--r-- 1 rici rici 1.1G Nov 23 17:22 sparse
$ du -h sparse
4.0K    sparse
```

The file I created has one 4 kilobyte block on disk, of which only the first four characters are used. But if you read the file in the normal fashion (sequentially from the beginning) you'll have to read through a gigabyte of zeros before you encounter the `foo`.

On Linux, `du` is normally able to report the actual disk usage of a sparse file. You can tell it to report the "apparent size" (which will be more similar to what `ls -l` reports) by passing it the `-b` option. That's a Gnu extension; Posix does not require `du` to be accurate in its reporting of sparse file sizes. ("It is up to the implementation to define exactly how accurate its methods are.")

Presumably, `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` does something rather similar to the `dd` example above, in that it expands the ELF-formatted `exe` into a RAM image, and populates the image by seeking rather than filling the file with zeros. This is, in fact, the classic use case for sparse files, which can be memory-mapped (`mmap`) without incurring a cost for unused blocks.

Comment: The links I referenced were basically saying this.

Comment: @slm: I only see one link; I skimmed through the first couple of screenfulls, but didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said it was "basically" saying this. You said it more concisely but lines like this: "I'd guess you requested the bin file to contain both RAM and FLASH area." are essentially saying that the file is loaded with sparse data. There's this SO link that I hadn't referenced here either yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725268/why-does-arm-none-eabi-size-report-the-data-section-to-be-0-even-though-i-am-us. Your answer is the "what", but we're still missing the "why".

Comment: Since `du` reports the apparent size the same as the size that `ls` reports, I'd say your guess that the file is sparse is almost certainly correct. See the OP's update to the question.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. The problem was the linker script. Effectively, objcopy was filling add.bin with zeros from the address 0x0000002c to 0xa000000. Thanks to all.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: A persian king sought a partner for his daughter. Three suitors applied. The king took them to his orange grove, where they sat at the side of his lake. A giant orange tree arched overhead. The king squinted at the lake, and asked, "what's that floating in the shade of the tree?". "Why, it's an orange," said the first suitor. The second looked carefully at the fruit, and responded, "No, it's a lemon." The third suitor waded out to the fruit and picked it up. "It's half of a lemon," he reported... Sometimes it is best to not to be *too* certain about what you think you see.

Comment: @rici - I always thought it was a sparse file 8-)

Comment: @DavidMartínez - can you please add the details of the fix to your Q at the bottom. That way if someone else comes across this they'll know *why* they're seeing a 2GB+ file (thanks to rici's A), and *how* to resolve it.